# backup file with current timestamp as a filename

Tags: mysql

I would like to name my automated  backup file with currenttimestamp as a filename
I have a procedure

```
drop procedure if exists backup1;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `backup1`()
BEGIN
select * from employee_master
INTO outfile 'C://auto_backup/current_timestamp.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
END
```

and here is my event

```
drop event if exists backup_file;
set global event_scheduler=on;
CREATE EVENT backup_file
ON SCHEDULE
every 10 second
DO CALL backup1;
```

Someone help me to solve this

Comment: Use dynamic sql to generate the select statement.

Comment: yup I have tried that using concat but not working

Comment: Current timestamp would be an invalid file name on a windows system.

Comment: yup what shud i do alternately

Comment: You could use replace to fix the offending dashs,colons (and spaces). And maybe concat a table name as a prefix.